# Why does this red color fill only one frame PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

Alright so I have some code that takes user input, fetches each letter's corresponding gif (a dancing letter) and stitches them together to form a word. Kind of like an animated font, basically.

My problem is that with PIL, it occasionally fills the background of one of the letters for around 1 frame with a red color, as demonstrated here:

[image: demo]

This is my code that generates this

```py
import sys
from PIL import Image
from PIL import GifImagePlugin
from io import BytesIO
def text(str, procid):
  t = []
  for c in str:
    t.append('letters/' + c + '.gif')
  images = [Image.open(x) for x in t]
  widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
  total_width = sum(widths)
  max_height = max(heights)
  x_offset = 0
  imgs = []
  for frame in range(0, images[0].n_frames):
      new = Image.new('RGBA', (total_width, max_height))
      x_offset = 0
      for im in images:
          im.seek(frame)
          new.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
          x_offset += im.size[0]
      imgs.append(new)

  img_io = BytesIO()
  new.save(img_io, 'GIF', transparency=0, save_all=True, append_images=imgs, loop=0, disposal=2,duration=1,optimize=True)
  img_io.seek(0)
  return img_io
```

Any ideas as to why it does this, and is it possible to fix this?

Edit: I've attached the input GIFS used to create the animated "TEST"

e.gif https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQfMK.gif

s.gif https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PQp5.gif

t.gif https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMLrg.gif

Edit 2: All the letters have the same amount of frames, and the red background is not present anywhere in S.gif meaning it has to be a PIL problem or a problem with my code.

Comment: If it helps, I checked each GIF and the frames do not contain this artifact. Also, the number of frames per GIF that I'm combining into one differs between letter (might be the cause).

Comment: What does `im.seek(frame)` return if the frame is not found?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the .gif for the letter S — try changing it to one of the others that does not exhibit the problem.

Comment: How can we help you when you don't share your input images and your code is incomplete without `import` statements?

Comment: Can you post the individual gifs?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I believe it just copies the previous frame

Comment: @MarkSetchell updated the question to contain the entire code

Comment: @Shivam Updated the question to show the individual gifs

Comment: Did you try using a different letter as I suggested? If so, what happened?

Comment: Does letter S gif has more or less frames compared to the others ??

Comment: @pippo1980 I believe so

Comment: @martineau some other letters exhibit the problem, so its not just S. In fact quite a handful of letters do. I assume it may have to do with a difference in frame numbers?

Comment: @pippo1980 actually no, the letter S has the same number of frames as the rest of the gifs. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by downloading a different set of the same dancing letters from a somewhat more reputable source. (The previous ones were uploaded to tenor so it could've been modified in some ways)

Answer (score 0):

to me there is more going on,

check one of the  s.gif frames :

[image]

and nevertheless my output gif using your code looks like:

[image]